# How would I check if a folders contents has changed with PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, ms-word, directory, documents

I've been issued with the task of when an e-mail is sent to a specific e-mail address it should upload it to a folder called 'input' I have to check this folder for changes to see if there are any .PDF files in so I can allow them through to be converted to a .DOC file and be stored in another folder called 'output' and then send it back to the user that e-mailed it, where would I start with this?!

Answer (score 3):

You could store the `md5` of the folder content in some place (database, file, cookies..) and then if the folder contents change, the `md5` will also change.

[More about md5.](http://php.net/manual/es/function.md5.php)

You can find a function for it [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php#75393).

Comment: or by [md5_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php) or [sha1_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sha1-file.php)

Comment: This seems like a good answer, but how would I do it so that when the user e-mails the file it renames the file dependent on the e-mail it is sent from? I assume I have to do something with POP but I'm not sure what? The last part of e-mailing it back is fine, I'm connected through the SMTP server and using something called mailer to send it back it's just becoming a bit of a pain

Comment: That's another different question. Open a new one for it.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like:

```
<?php
 $filename = '/path/to/input_folder/yourfile.pdf';

 if (file_exists($filename)) {
    //do convert to  .doc
 } else {
    //do something else
 }
?>
```

just [explore file-related php funcion](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

Comment: Thanks I will make use of this would this work

    <?php
        $allowedExtensions = array ("pdf");
        $filename = '/path/to/input_folder/yourfile.pdf';

             if (file_exists($filename && $allowedExtensions)) {
                  //do convert to  .doc
             } else {
                   //do something else
             }
     ?>

Comment: do you want to check the file extension first?

Comment: Yes it HAS to be of .pdf format to be able to go through if it's not then delete it and send the user an e-mail saying "error blah blah blah"

Comment: if so, you have to (and it is recommended due to security) check-it **before** you upload it into 'input' folder.